# Does locking in gnome allow background tasks like uplaoding to keep running?

Tags: gnome, background-process, sleep, lock

I am uploading things in the back and want to lock the screen, but am not sure if the `lock` function in gnome locks the screen while allowing that to continue.

So far it seems that the computer is not going into hibernation so that is good, but will it keep at it that way? I don't want it to go into sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the first part of your question: no, locking the screen will not stop running processes.  The second part depends on your sleep settings. If your system is setup to sleep after some idle period, that will still apply even in the lock screen.

The easy way to show this is to have music playing and lock the screen.  The music playback will not stop.